# Antlr4 parser not parsing reassignment statement correctly

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I've been creating a grammar parser using Antlr4 and wanted to add variable reassignment (without having to declare a new variable)

I've tried changing the reassignment statement to be an expression, but that didn't change anything

Here's a shortened version of my grammar:

```
grammar MyLanguage;

program: statement* EOF;

statement
    : expression EOC
    | variable EOC 
    | IDENTIFIER ASSIGNMENT expression EOC
    ;

variable: type IDENTIFIER (ASSIGNMENT expression)?;

expression
    : STRING
    | INTEGER
    | IDENTIFIER
    | expression MATH expression
    | ('+' | '-') expression
    ;

MATH:       '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | '%' | '//' | '**';
ASSIGNMENT: MATH? '=';
EOC:        ';';
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

STRING:     '"' (~[\u0000-\u0008\u0010-\u001F"] | [\t])* '"' | '\'' (~[\u0000-\u0008\u0010-\u001F'] | [\t])* '\'';
INTEGER:    '0' | ('+' | '-')? [1-9][0-9]*;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

type:      'str';
```

if anything else might be of relevance, please ask

so I tried to parse

```
str test = "empty";
test = "not empty";
```

which worked, but when I tried (part of the fibbionaci function)

```
temp = n1;
n1 = n1 + n2;
n2 = temp;
```

it got an error and parsed it as

```
temp = n1; //statement
n1 = n1 //statement - <missing ';'>
+n2; //statement
n2 = temp; //statement
```

Comment: Does it parse `n1 + n2` when no assignment is involved? If it works until you introduce an addition, then maybe the addition is the problem, not the assignment.

Comment: Please include all the definitions so that someone would be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @sepp2k it seems so, i never tested that on its own and this was the result:
`n1 /*statement - no viable alternative*/ +n2; //statement`

Comment: @BilltheLizard I added all to this relevant definitions (no other statement is having any problems)

Comment: @Dia.Frost Still doesn't compile for me. After I add `grammar fileName;` at the beginning, I get "reference to undefined rule" for `WHITESPACE` and `constant_mod`. Please post a version of your code that compiles and reproduces the problem (ideally you'd remove all the parts that aren't relevant to the problem, but still test the shortened version to make sure it compiles and still exhibits the problem).

Comment: @sepp2k I've gone through each line and took the definition for everything, it should compile upon adding "grammar [filename]"

Comment: @Dia.Frost The code you posted still gave me a "must label all alternatives or none" error, so I've removed all labels. It also does not contain any rule that would actually match your inputs (even the ones that you've said work correctly), so I've added a rule that matches multiple statements. *Then* I could reproduce your problem. I've also removed everything I could that wouldn't make the error go away. In the future, please do this yourself.

Comment: @sepp2k I’ll remember that and I didn’t know what exactly was all relevant to the question, but I cut out all that didn’t use any operators, as for the grammar and program, I forgot that one has to add those (my `grun` command only requires the (-gui or -tree argument, the grammar name and file to test, which generate the parser, compiles it and then calls the TestRig tool)

Comment: "I didn’t know what exactly was all relevant to the question" You find that out by removing anything that might be irrelevant and then test to make sure that the problem still exists. If the problem no longer occurs, you've removed something that was relevant to the problem, so you'll need to add it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with assignment statements. Additions simply don't work at all - whether they're part of an assignment or not. So the simplest input to get the error would be `x+y;`. If you print the token stream for that input (using `grun` with the `-tokens` option for example), you'll get the following output:

```
[@0,0:0='x',<IDENTIFIER>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='+',<'+'>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='y',<IDENTIFIER>,1:2]
[@3,3:3=';',<';'>,1:3]
[@4,4:3='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:4]
line 1:1 no viable alternative at input 'x+'
```

Now compare this to `x*y;`, which works fine:

```
[@0,0:0='x',<IDENTIFIER>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='*',<MATH>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='y',<IDENTIFIER>,1:2]
[@3,3:3=';',<';'>,1:3]
[@4,4:3='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:4]
```

The important difference here is that `*` is recognized as a `MATH` token, but `+` isn't. It's recognized as a `'+'` token instead.

This happens because you introduced a separate `'+'` (and `'-'`) token type in the alternative `| ('+' | '-') expression`. So whenever the lexer sees a `+` it produces a `'+'` token, not a `MATH` token, because string literals in parser rules take precedence over named lexer rules.

If you turn `MATH` into a parser rule `math` (or maybe `mathOperator`) instead, all of the operators will be literals and the problem will go away. That said, you probably don't want a single rule for all math operators because that doesn't give you the precedence you want, but that's a different issue.

PS: Something like `x+1` still won't work because it will see `+1` as a single `INTEGER` token. You can fix that by removing the leading `+` and `-` from the `INTEGER` rule (that way `x = -2` would be parsed as a unary minus applied to the integer `2` instead of just the integer `-2`, but that's not a problem).

Comment: The MATH token is actually already split in my original grammar, so that isn’t an issue, I’ll try changing it to a parser rule.